# App Store not showing update button when new version is available

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, phonegap-build

I have released the update of iOS app on iTunes. It is available on App store but neither it is showing in 'updates' tab nor it is updating automatically. Finally i uninstalled the old version and installed the new version from the app store.
This iOS app is developed in phonegap.

Comment: You need to phrase your question better -- be more specific. Maybe attach a screenshot of the webpages you're describing.

Comment: The issue is whenever i release the update for my iOS app, it is not reflecting in the 'Updates' tab of App store in iPhone.

Comment: Have you submitted the app for Approval at  https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ yet? You've to do this for every update.

Comment: Yes i have submitted. It is approved and available in app store. Once it is approved it has to come in 'Updates' tab to update the older version in my phone. But it is not listed in the Updates tab. Instead it is showing 'open' when i search it on app store.

Answer (score 6):

You should wait a few hours before a device finds the updated version of your approved application. The application update needs to be distributed to multiple servers dedicated to the App Store.

It is possible to manually check for updates on your device since iOS 11. Tap near the top of the screen near the ‘Updates’ text, then hold and pull down, then release.

Please note that you will not get the update automatically when you see a download button on your application page in the App Store. This means that the version on your device is signed with a different certificate than the released version in the App Store. Simply click on the download button to resolve this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You also had the opportunity prior to iOS11 to clear your personal AppStore Cache on the device by tapping 10x on the "Highlights" Tab on the TabBarController ;-)

Comment: The application is released a week ago. and the certificates used are same as before. Even i tried the solutions you have mentioned above, But still it is giving an issue.

Comment: @Kiran did your app ever show the Update button? I'm having a similar issue. The App is available in the app store, the changelog and new screenshots can be seen. The device is confirmed to be running an older version, but the app store page still shows as `open`

Comment: @Bejasc have you found any solution because i faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open bug from apple side since last 5 years which is still yet to be fixed.

For reference kindly check their official site :
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52767?page=3